# How fixed function access to the class data member?

Tags: c++

When running the program, I encounter this error message:

'number' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object.

Is there a way that the function setNumber can change the number data ?

```
    #pragma once
class ho1
{
    int number;
public:
    ho1();
    void setNumber(int x)const 
    {
        number = x;
    };

};
```

Comment: You've declared the function const...

Comment: ... Which begs the question, *why is it* const to begin with? The name implies it shouldn't be.

Comment: Why use `setNumber` at all when `number` could just be `public`?

Comment: To summarize others' comments: Don't contradict yourself.

Comment: For that, I have to use a constant type.

Comment: @Hooman.AS _For that, I have to use a constant type._ Use `mutable int number;` then.

Comment: It makes very little sense to use `const` for a function whose semantics are to mutate the object.

Comment: It was just a challenge at the university And I thought that if I put it here I would answer the question sooner but I got a downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `setNumber` const, Which means this function will not change any member of the class. Just remove `const` from function implementation.

```
class ho1
{
    int number;
public:
    ho1();
    void setNumber(int x)
    {
        number = x;
    };

};
```